# Time difference between all particles and waves

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, time, spacetime-dimensions, time-evolution

Since all elementary particles and waves were created simultaneously in the big-bang (t0) would there be any time difference between any interacting elementary particles and/or waves after t0? I'm assuming that all the energy and information present in our universe today was present at t0. Which implies to me that everything today has shared information in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Once the collision energies get above a few MeV particles are surprisingly transient objects. Even the early particle colliders were able to create and destroy particles, and the Large Hadron Collider creates hundreds of new particles with every collision.

As we approach the Big Bang the energy becomes orders of magnitudes larger than anything possible at the LHC, so particles were being created all over the place in a chaotic and random fashion. The result is that the particles we see today were not created at the same time or in any form of synchronised process. They will have been created at random times by random and unrelated processes.

So the end result is that we cannot expect any two particles chosen at random to have properties that are correlated due to them being created at the same instant.

Comment: It might have and did destroy particles but not the energy, which is the crux of this question.